# Maximize a sum of log of sum

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, global-optimization

For a matrix $c (m\times n)$ of non-negative constants, find values of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ that satisfy $\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k = 1$, $\lambda_k \ge  0 \, \forall k$ and maximize

\begin{equation*}
L = \sum_{i=1}^m \log \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k c_{i,k}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: I am on a project relating to machine learning. I need to find lambda values that best match data, constant matrix c in this case

Comment: This is a concave maximization problem, just use any convex optimization approach...

Comment: I will study more. Can you recommend some method that is suitable for this problem? Does it converge in this case?

Comment: Try using http://cvxr.com on some small problems to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an extended comment.

The problem is equivalent to maximizing 
$$e^L = \prod_{i=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k c_{i,k}.$$

By the AGM inequality, we have
$$e^L \leq \left( \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k c_{i,k} \right)^m = \left( \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k C_k\right)^m,$$
where $C_k = \sum_{i=1}^m c_{i,k}$.

It is easy to maximize this upper bound. Namely,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k C_k \leq \max_k C_k = C_{k_0},$$
where equality can be achieved by taking $\lambda_{k_0} = 1$ and all the other $\lambda$'s equal 0. Therefore,
$$e^L \leq \left( \frac{C_{k_0}}{m} \right)^m$$
and thus 
$$L \leq m\log \frac{C_{k_0}}{m}.$$

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot. But in our application, $n$ is so small, while $m$ is much greater than n, so the equality condition of the AGM inequality rarely occurs. Futher more, I am interested in the $\lambda$ values, not the maximum L values. However, thanks for the upper bound.

Comment: @Vuong Bui: This analysis suggests that $\lambda$'s should be biased towards the indices $k$ with large column sums $C_k$.